# Deserializing JSON key corresponding to a parent entity reference (Symfony Serializer)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, symfony5

Let's say I have a simple Post entity, with a $author ManyToOne relation :

```js
Class Post {
     /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Author::class, inversedBy="posts")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $author;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $title;
    
    ...
}
```

Then a controller function like this :

```js
public function create(Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $em, SerializerInterface $serializer): Response
    {
        $data = $request->getContent();

        $post = $serializer->deserialize($data, Post::class, 'json');

        $em->persist($post);
        $em->flush();
    }
```

With a JSON format $data looking like this :

```js
{
    "author": { "id": 10 },
    "title": "My Title",
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to make Serializer deserialize the author['id'] to it's entity reference ?

I read that this is what the [PropertyInfo component of Symfony](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/property_info.html) is supposed to do when enabled. But even with PropertyInfo enabled, the persist operation is still creating a new Author instead of refering to an existing one (Doctrine generates a new author row instead of setting the author_id of the post row)

Comment: I've had issues using Serializer on entities, problems with recursion and such with deeply nested, complex relationships. Maybe JMSSerializerBundle would work better?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe by adding `cascade={"persist"}` on $author property annotation ?
Or forcing setter `

$post = $serializer->deserialize($data, Post::class, 'json');

$post->setAuthor($em->getRepository(Author::class)->findOneBy([]));
`